# System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie goes on error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

It keeps giving me error ("Object reference not set to an object instance") while running SetAuthCookie. The line that goes wrong is this:

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(TokenManager.GenerateToken(utente.IDUtente, true), true);
```

where TokenManager.GenerateToken is our function to generate a token (string)

I'm sure it's not the GenerateToken that creates the error because I assigned the result of the function to a variable and then used the variable inside the SetAuthToken and the error comes from SetAuthToken

```
var newToken = TokenManager.GenerateToken(utente.IDUtente, true);
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(newToken, true);
```

I tried that too, but it still gives the same error...

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("foo", false);
```

Since they deleted the last question I asked, I specify that SetAuthToken is external code, therefore not mine, and therefore I don't need to resolve the "Object reference not set to an object instance", but understand why the function generates this error.

Some advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am sure it's nothing to do SetAuthCookie() method but the method you seem to be calling inside it.
Please check again. Could utente be null?

Comment: i tried using the string "foo" and it still gives the error @Shad

Comment: Are you calling this method inside an Action method()?

Comment: yup, it's an async Task<ActionResult> method @Shad

Comment: Weird. I hope you have entry in the web.config as well? If yes, Could you also check if you are able to get the HTTP Context.
                `HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;`

Comment: I can't do a HttpContext.Current, I only have HttpContext.CurrentHandler or HttpContext.CurrentNotification @Shad

Comment: entry in the web.config file for FormsAuthentication is there or not?

Comment: yes... i have that 

<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH_FE" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="89280" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication> @Shad